# How to get filepath from inside text file and perform operation in bash

Tags: linux, bash, file-permissions

I have list of folders path like

```
/home/user/wwww
/home/www/www/temp
```

They are stored in a text file . Now i want get those path for dir names and make them all 777 permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do chmod 777 "$line"; done
```

This will change mode to 77 for each "$line" in input file file.txt.

Comment: It would be worth saying `"$line"` (quoted) so that paths with spaces do not cause gratuitous failures.